# How to combine or collate container log entries from Azure Log Analytics work space into XML data?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-aks, kql, azure-log-analytics

Our application writes the logs in container subsequently in Azure Log Analytics workspace. The data is some times records and sometimes it is XML data. In Log Analytics work space each line is an entry record, I want to combine the XML records as one XML node which will be easier to read for the developers. How to achieve this please help.

[image]

Comment: The elementary thing to do would be to write the logs properly, that is the whole XML as a single log entry. Any reason you are not doing it?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz that is the default log writing by TIBCO BWCE. Not sure if we can do any change to that.

Comment: Definitely worth checking

Answer (score 0):

One way of attempting this

```
let stacktrace = datatable(ts:string, line:string)
[
    "A", "<root>", 
    "A", "<line1>L1", 
    "A", "</line1>", 
    "A", "<line2/>", 
    "A", "</root>" ,
    "B", "<root>", 
    "B", "<line1>L1", 
    "B", "</line1>", 
    "B", "<line2/>", 
    "B", "</root>" 

];
stacktrace
| summarize linegroup = make_list(strcat(line)) by ts
| extend singleline = strcat_array(linegroup, "")
| project-away linegroup
```

gives the following results

```
A   <root><line1>L1</line1><line2/></root>
B   <root><line1>L1</line1><line2/></root>
```

Drawback : The grouping is by TS , multiple exceptions in the same TS will get grouped. Adding other unique keys for the group will break the tie